# c# add existing webparts on site into sandbox webpart solution

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, content-editor-web-part

I want to create a webpart using sandbox webpart solution on C# which contents two or more webparts (such as a list, task, document,...) existed on my Sharepoint site.
So my new webpart will have some specified webparts I needed and some custom actions I wanted.

Any solution for this requirement of business solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231562.aspx) article Sandboxed Solutions support both custom actions as well as visual web parts.

The following are not supported.

- Application Pages
- Custom Action Group
- Farm-scoped features
- HideCustomAction element
- Web Application-scoped features
- Workflows with code

Comment: Yes, it's helpful information. Could you mind giving me a way of implement that solution? Thanks

Comment: Refer this article for adding webparts. http://avinash-moss-expert.blogspot.de/2010/08/add-web-part-programmatically-using.html

Comment: Sorry Malin DeSilva for this unconvenience because SharePoint 2013 doesn't support API for adding webpart like DLL `SPLimitedWebPartManager` in Microsoft.SharePoint.